# civimcrestface-wordpress get "Unable to decode supplied JSON"

Tags: wordpress

I try to get civimcrestface-wordpress working. I get the error "Unable to decode supplied JSON"
I used https://subdomain.domain.de/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/rest.php as URL.

Wordpress 5.7.2
CiviCRM 5.38.0

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution in https://github.com/CiviMRF/civimcrestface-wordpress/commit/f7f76ba0a8ab1fe602a17db5805af7769e95497d

It works after I used the URL https://my-civi.org/wp-json/civicrm/v3/rest